# Запись данных из SerializerMethodField в поле model (django rest framework)

Tags: django, сериализация, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Новичок в Django. 
Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию по размеру файла (изображения) с помощью django-filter. Поиск размера файла я описал в сериалайзере (get_image_size), но для фильтра нужно, чтобы поле size было в моделях. 
Однако я не знаю как записать туда данные из сериалайзера.. как это сделать?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Snippet(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    size = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import filters
from mainapp.models import Snippet
from mainapp.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields = ('date', 'size')
    search_fields = ('date', 'size')
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from mainapp.models import Snippet
import os
from cleverbots import settings


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    size2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_size')
    print(type(size2)) # class 'rest_framework.fields.SerializerMethodField'

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'place', 'image', 'date', 'size2', 'size',)

    def get_image_size(self, obj):
        print(type(os.path.getsize(settings.BASE_DIR + obj.image.url))) # <class 'int'>
        return os.path.getsize(settings.BASE_DIR + obj.image.url)
```

**результат**

```
    "id": 1,
    "place": "home",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photo/favicon.png",
    "date": "2019-04-16T14:36:12.623999Z",
    "size2": 4789,
    "size": 0
```

**нужно**

```
    "id": 1,
    "place": "home",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/photo/favicon.png",
    "date": "2019-04-16T14:36:12.623999Z",
    "size2": 4789,
    "size": 4789
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SerializerMethodField` это поле **только для чтения**
Сохранить размер загруженного файла можно переопределив метод `perform_create` для `SnippetViewSet`:

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields = ('date', 'size')
    search_fields = ('date', 'size')

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(size=serializer.validated_data['image'].size)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)